# How to fetch Shopify Subscription in Native Mobile Apps?

Tags: android, ios, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-mobile-buy-sdk

I have created a store on Shopify and added one subscription app from Shopify AppStore. I can see my subscriptions in my demo app on the website provided by Shopify. I am building this store on Shopify so that I could access this subscription on my iOS and Android native apps. I tried reading the document and going through several links but I could not find fetching my subscriptions in native mobile-buy-SDKs or via GraphQL.

Could anyone please help me understand how I can fetch my subscriptions via GraphQL or Shopify's Mobile-buy-SDK on native platforms?

Thanks in advance.

(PS: The attached screenshot is the subscription that I have created on Shopify and which I wish to fetch on iOS and Android platforms.)

[image: Shopify Subscription I want to fetch]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after spending so many days I was able to figure this one out.
You can fetch subscription details via Graph API from Shopify. You'll need to add the GraphQL app to your Shopify store, which will help you to browse through your GQL queries smoothly. I wanted to get the Price, name, timeline of subscription(days, weeks, years), and currency. So here is the query for getting Shopify Subscriptions via GraphQL to your native apps.

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

```
{
  productByHandle(handle: "filter-coffee") {
    priceRangeV2 {
      maxVariantPrice {
        amount
        currencyCode
      }
    }
    sellingPlanGroups(first: 5) {
      edges {
        node {
          summary
          sellingPlans(first: 1) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                name
                description
                deliveryPolicy {
                  ... on SellingPlanRecurringDeliveryPolicy {
                    createdAt
                    interval
                    intervalCount
                  }
                }
                pricingPolicies {
                  ... on SellingPlanFixedPricingPolicy {
                    adjustmentType
                    adjustmentValue {
                      ... on SellingPlanPricingPolicyPercentageValue {
                        percentage
                      }
                    }
                    createdAt
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```